# Concatenate pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate a number of dataframes `sub_df` horizontally to form one large dataframe `df`.

`sub_df` are of the format:

```
     n1   n2   n3   ...   n1000   special_string
Id  
8    20   10   45   ...   100      >50,<200,2009-09-24
```

All of the `n1` to `n1000` are numerical columns, except for the last column `special_string` which is a special string with special characters.

Expected `df`:

```
Id   n1   n2   n3   ...   n1000   special_string
 
8    20   10   45   ...   100     >50,<200,2009-09-24
9    10   30   15   ...   10      <0,>-20,2009-11-02
10   20   15   25   ...   50      >40,>200,2010-03-04
...
```

In a for loop, I appended the `sub_df`s using:

```
sub_df_list = []
...

sub_df_list.append(sub_df)
```

This gives the `sub_df_list`. Then I tried to convert `sub_df_list` into a dataframe `df` using:

```
sub_df_list1= pd.concat(sub_df_list)
```

but it caught error:

```
TypeError: Expected tuple, got str
```

I tried to reset index of the `sub_df`s with `sub_df= sub_df.reset_index()` but the error remained.

I also noticed that it would work if removed the `special_string` column for the `sub_df`s but not when the column is present. Why did this error occur? Any contribution is appreciated.

---

Edit:

Not sure if this could be the reason. The original `sub_df`s only consist of columns `n1` to `n1000. The last column was added to` sub_df` with

```
    sub['x10081'] = some_value_i
```

Could this change the data type somehow from `tuple` to `string` that is not recognised by `pd.concat`?

Comment: Your code is no reproducible. It's worked if I concat your two dataframes.

Comment: Hi @Corralien thank you for your feedback, however my code still didn't work - could editing the `sub_df`s change the data type(although it doesn't look like it as `type(sub_df)` returned `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`)? Please see my question edit.